# Boostrap 4 img-responsive does not work fully

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Since bootstrap 4 came out i'm using it.

I saw you can't use the.

```
class="img-responsive"
```

So i used this:

```
.img-fluid{
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

But it does not work fully cause when i half the screen it's only img-fluid,
Is there a way to let it work like the img-responsive or does it needs to be fixed?

Greets,

Conan

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 4, the `.img-responsive` is changed to be `.img-fluid`. For more info about migrations from BS3 to BS4 visit this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)

Comment: I tried to like put it in like this 

    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="slide3.jpg" alt="Third slide">

But when i minimize the screen i see a white square is this normal in bootstrap 4?

Comment: Is your image present in a carousel?

Comment: Ye i did it like in the carousel thingy in bootstrap

Comment: Can you add your results in the post?

Comment: That is what i see when i minimize the window

Comment: You should supply the  source code where the problem is. So I can help you.

Comment: Could i add u for that on skype or something like that?

Comment: Is sended u a mail

Answer (score 0):

you can add this class`card-img-top`

**HTML**

```
<img src="your images link" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `<img class="img-fluid" src="myimage.png">` and it works fine.

When I minimize my screen, the image also minimize automatically (it scales with the parent element).

Maybe you can post some code, so we can understand ur problem better?